# IdentityServer3 Authentication with Nancy

Tags: nancy, identityserver3

**How do I do IdentityServer3 authentication with Nancy?**

There's OpenID authentication with Nancy, there's Active Directory authentication with Nancy. There's easy forms authentication with Nancy. **How do I do IdentityServer3 authentication and authorization with Nancy?**

- Is there a short and easy way to do this?
- Do I need to create the IUserMapper stuff?
- Should I use the Nuget for Forms Authentication (for my UI views)?
- Should I use the Nancy Token Authentication?
- Is there a difference if I'm authenticating (and authorizing) for a UI view or for a RESTFull API call?  (i.e. do I need to choose between the "implicit flow" / "code flow" / "hybrid flow" or can I just work with the code flow?)
- Will it make a difference what kind of store IdentityServer3 is looking at?
- Do I need to set anything special up on the IDSrv3 (like the clients definition)? And can / should that be done in the IDSrv3 config file?

I want to set the login screen to go to IDSrv3 and then come back with a token and claims (roles).

Comment: anybody?  your thoughts? please!!!

Comment: I have no idea what identity server 3 is :(

Comment: Having a look at their github website, it's just an OAuth provider, so it would be a case of implementing a provider in Simple Authentication and then using it. Coupled with Forms Authentication for your application.

Comment: No, I'm not asking what to do in the identity server.

I'm asking what I need to do in **Nancy** to get my APIs to authenticate and authorize with what is returned by IDSrv3. And then what to do in **Nancy** to get my UIs to authenticate and authorize with the IDSrv3. 

IDSrv3 is basically a custom OpenID-Connect server, that can serve in between the consumer and the actual OpenID-Connect provider (i.e. Google, Facebook, or my own identity system, be it ASP.Net Security, Active Directory, or a simpler and easily customized MembershipReboot, from the same guys that made IDSrv3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I understand correctly: (please note edits at end of this post)

1. **API Only** If your only serving APIs (with no interactive views) i.e. if you are not serving a UI, then you will be interacting with the OP (the OpenID-Connect Provider, - in this case the IdentityServer3 server), only AFTER you logged in via the OP from a different project (with SSO - Single Sign On), and only after that app will have received an Access-Token in return from the OP. You will be using BearerTokenAuthentication middleware to authenticate the access-token.

The IdentityServer3 needs to expect your call, so you need to be registered as a client.

1.1 **Without resources:** If you are only authorizing the APIs (typically by role) all you have to do is decorate with [Authorize(Roles="role1,role2")]. When calling the API (with https!!) you add the TokenBearer and everything is done automatically for you.

1.2 **With resources:** If you are also serving resources according to user consent and claims (typically again according to the user's roles), you should use an AuthorizationManager as recommended in the IdentityServer simple MVC and API step-trough doc.

2. **UI**: If though you are running a UI that needs login, you must add cookies authentication (Nuget), then open id connect authentication (follow the MVC example, Nuget the IdentityServer3.OpenIdConnect Authentication).
   This will cause your app to run with the **"hybrid flow"** so that your first call brings back an id_token and an access_token. You store both tokens in the cookie (by using notifications). You then use the id_token when logging out, otherwise the browser allows "replay".

You use the access_token to call your APIs with (in the same way as before) and they in turn return the scopes and claims.

3. **Client Credentials Authentication** A third option is for unmanned (no user login) automatic network calls. In that case use "Client Credentials" logging into IDServ3 by setting a "secret" in the IDServ3 and using that secret along with the "client name" when calling the IDServ3 to get a list of "scopes" with "claims", with which your API can decide to authorize or deny access.

---

Edited:

It turns out that there are several more steps needed for the API getting Authorize[Roles="roles1,roles2"] to work.

For the Authorize to work in MVC you must either make a custom MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute class, checking for claims of type "role", or you must change your identity server code to return ClaimTypes.Role in the user's role claims and to have a scope with ScopeType=ID that includes the ClaimTypes.Role roles. The client must allow this new scope to be requested.

Then you have to request that scope in the MVC startup class, and NOT have the claims transformation line turning the claims into a dictionary set of simple string.

Now for the API authorization to work is even harder:

Requesting "id_token token" responsetype in the calling ui will give an access_token without the roles in the claims. This is because only a scope with ScopeType=Resource is attached to the access_token. So:

- you need ANOTHER scope with ScopeType=Resource with the roles,
- and the client in the idsrv3 has to allow that scope being requested,
- and you need to request that scope in the startup code of the API project, along with the bearer-token startup code.
- Finally, becuase its resource-type scope, the Authorize will work but the Roles=...  will not, unless you create your own MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute class, that checks the role.

Comment: I was wrong about the "not checking roles" it will check the role if you add the claims transformation line at the beginning of your startup code of your receiving app (the webapi app and/or the mvc app), and create the claims with the simple type "role".

Comment: Any idea on how to do basic authentication (username and password)?  I want to pass this to the identity server and not sure how to form my URL.